# How can I make only confirmed user as valid user at default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using `Devise` and its confirm option.
As you know, a user won't be activated unless the user clicks on the link in Confirmation mail.

The problem I have here is, we can see all the members including the user who hasn't confirmed yet!

> @users = User.all will fetch all the users! I don't want to include
>   un-confirmed users.

Is there any technique to ignore those who haven't confirmed yet?
Adding something in User model will be the best!

Please help me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding a scope to your User model for consistent access:

```
class User

  def self.unconfirmed
    where('users.confirmed_at is null')
  end

  def self.confirmed
    where('users.confirmed_at is not null')
  end

end
```

Then in controllers (or other models), this list can be accessed as:

```
@users = User.confirmed
```

The beauty of scopes is that they could be chained further:

```
@unformed_males = User.confirmed.where(:sex => 'male').order(:height)
```

You get the idea ;)

HTH

Comment: Thanks but your code is to fetch unconfirmed user. I want opposite. How can I exclude it?

Comment: Can you do the opposite? naming it confirmed please!

Comment: Edited answer :). Sorry for not reading your question better :(

Answer (score 1):

Devise will give you the attribute `confirmed_at`. You can use:

```
@user = User.where('confirmed_at IS NOT NULL')
```

And, if I am not mistaken, after confirmation Devise sets the confirmation_token to NULL so that it can't be used again, so you could also do:

```
@user = User.where('confirmation_token IS NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise adds confirmed_at column to your users table. So you can use as follows:

```
     @users = User.all(:conditions => ["confirmed_at is not null"])
```

Comment: No, this is old rails 2 syntax. Use `User.where` instead.

Comment: He didn't mention any version. My answer is also correct. Why did you down vote

Comment: If the user doesn't mention any version, I specifically encourage you to use the latest syntax. But nobody said I wouldn't upvote again if you corrected it ;-)